# How do I assign a File into a variable to work with that variable?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I want to assign a file into a variable inside a shell script; the file name would come from command line argument. For example I want to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
file1 = $1
file2 = $2
```

Then I want to read `file1` line by line using the variable `file1`, but every time I get an error saying ***permission denied***. How do I access the file using the variable name?

Comment: Remove the spaces before and after `=`s and enclose the command line arguments in double quotes, i.e. `file1="$1"`

Comment: @fpmurphy Actually you don't need to quote the right-hand side of an a assignment. (It doesn't hurt, but it's unnecessary.)

Comment: @tripleee.  Depends, what if the filenames include spaces, newlines, etc?  While it is recommended that filenames be limited to the Portable Character Set, it is not a requirement.

Comment: Can you demonstrate a case where quoting is actually necessary? No matter how I try, I can assign any value I want without quoting if I already managed to get it into `$1`.